How to Create HTTPS SSL Certificate on MacOS?
I am using MacOS 15.0 and need to set up a SSL ASP.NET Core developer certificate in order to work on my current project in the Rider IDE. I have no localhost or ASP.NET certificate preexisting in my keychain, but every time I try to run the command(s) in order to create a SSL certificate, I will get an error message such as:
There was an error creating the HTTPS developer certificate.

There are also screenshots with the errors from the IDE and console.
error in console
I have already tried to set up / create the certificate manually in the keychain and running commands in the console, but as soon as I get to the part to import the .pfx file to the keychain ("sudo security import ~/localhost-dev.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db") I will also get an error message despite of using the right / using no password:
security: SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)


Please [edit] your question to replace the console output image with the text contained in that image, formatted in a [code block].

Apple introduced a breaking change in macOS that breaks existing .NET SDK. You have to wait for updated .NET SDK releases.
Workarounds are being collected in this GitHub thread.

I have actually found a work-around to add a functioning localhost certificate posted yesterday!
https://dev.to/michaelcharles/fixing-the-https-developer-certificate-error-in-net-on-macos-sequoia-516h
Big props to pvasek and kalebzettl (GitHub)!

If you're posting this as an answer, perhaps consider providing some of the details in here too. Otherwise if the blog post is taken down then this answer isn't any use. Or if you are only providing the blog post link then just add it as a Comment instead.
